# JSON.parse() - SyntaxError: Expected end of stream at char 2

Tags: javascript, json, google-sheets, sjcl

In my [project](https://github.com/TheNilesh/password-manager/tree/master/Password-Manager), I have written google spreadsheet script to decipher encrypted cell content using sjcl. But I failed.

```
function encryptCell() {
  var masterKey = Browser.inputBox('Enter masterKey');
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var cell = spreadSheet.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
  var input = cell.getValue();

  var encJson = sjcl.encrypt(masterKey, input);
/*
{"iv":"4psT+LTIh/aT7WWv7Ye7qw==","v":1,"iter":1000,"ks":128,"ts":64,"mode":"ccm","adata":"","cipher":"aes","salt":"PjSOiia9TCM=","ct":"3hwmBbwQ7y/fsjk="}
*/
  var encStr = JSON.stringify(encJson);
/*
"{\"iv\":\"4psT+LTIh/aT7WWv7Ye7qw==\",\"v\":1,\"iter\":1000,\"ks\":128,\"ts\":64,\"mode\":\"ccm\",\"adata\":\"\",\"cipher\":\"aes\",\"salt\":\"PjSOiia9TCM=\",\"ct\":\"3hwmBbwQ7y/fsjk=\"}"
*/
  var encB64 = Utilities.base64Encode(encStr);
  Browser.msgBox(encB64);

  var rencStr = Utilities.base64Decode(encB64);
/*
34,123,92,34,105,118,92,34,58,92,34,52,112,115,84,43,76,84,73,104,47,97,84,55,87,87,118,55,89,101,55,113,119,61,61,92,34,44,92,34,118,92,34,58,49,44,92,34,105,116,101,114,92,34,58,49,48,48,48,44,92,34,107,115,92,34,58,49,50,56,44,92,34,116,115,92,34,58,54,52,44,92,34,109,111,100,101,92,34,58,92,34,99,99,109,92,34,44,92,34,97,100,97,116,97,92,34,58,92,34,92,34,44,92,34,99,105,112,104,101,114,92,34,58,92,34,97,101,115,92,34,44,92,34,115,97,108,116,92,34,58,92,34,80,106,83,79,105,105,97,57,84,67,77,61,92,34,44,92,34,99,116,92,34,58,92,34,51,104,119,109,66,98,119,81,55,121,47,102,115,106,107,61,92,34,125,34
*/
  var rencJson = JSON.parse(rencStr);
  var rinput = sjcl.decrypt(masterKey, rencJson);
  Browser.msgBox(rinput);
}
```

Encryption is fine, which I can decrypt using [this tool](http://ctrlq.org/decrypt/). Something is wrong with `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: Print the JSON out, what does it look like?

Comment: forgot to mention, I have included _sjcl.min.js_ contents into google script.

Comment: Thanks @Corvusoft. solution is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20210010/4417818)

Comment: No a problem at all, enjoy your day.

Answer (score 1):

```
  var rencStr = Utilities.base64Decode(encB64);
/*
34,123,92,34,105,118,92,34,58,92,34,52,112,115,84,43,76,84,73,104,47,97,84,55,87,87,118,55,89,101,55,113,119,61,61,92,34,44,92,34,118,92,34,58,49,44,92,34,105,116,101,114,92,34,58,49,48,48,48,44,92,34,107,115,92,34,58,49,50,56,44,92,34,116,115,92,34,58,54,52,44,92,34,109,111,100,101,92,34,58,92,34,99,99,109,92,34,44,92,34,97,100,97,116,97,92,34,58,92,34,92,34,44,92,34,99,105,112,104,101,114,92,34,58,92,34,97,101,115,92,34,44,92,34,115,97,108,116,92,34,58,92,34,80,106,83,79,105,105,97,57,84,67,77,61,92,34,44,92,34,99,116,92,34,58,92,34,51,104,119,109,66,98,119,81,55,121,47,102,115,106,107,61,92,34,125,34
*/
```

If you take a look, that's not JSON. did you possibly miss the  `JSON.stringify();` step for that one?

You can't parse it if it's not JSON.

Answer (score 1):

When decoding with `Utilities.base64Decode()` you have one extra step to follow if you want to get a string back. If you look at the [Google Scripts reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#base64Decode(String,Charset)) it says that `base64Decode` returns a byte array and not a string. Looking at your code, your decode returns

```
var rencStr = Utilities.base64Decode(encB64);
/*34,123,92,34,105,118,92,34,58,92,34,52,112,115,84,43,76,84,73,104,47,97,84...*/
```

which is a numeric representation of your string in Unicode. If you run your return value through `Utilities.newBlob(rencStr).getDataAsString()` as the reference recommends, you will have your JSON that you can parse back into your encrypted string.